# Can I write to a HDF5 file from multiple processes/threads?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, bigdata, hdf5, netcdf4

Does hdf5 support parallel writes to the same file, from different threads or from different processes? Alternatively, does hdf5 support non-blocking writes?

If so then is this also supported by NetCDF4, and by the python bindings for either?

I am writing an application where I want different CPU cores to concurrently compute output intended for non-overlapping tiles of a very large output array. (Later I will want to read sections from it as a single array, without needing my own driver to manage indexing many separate files, and ideally without the additional IO task of rearranging it on disk.)

Answer (score 4):

Not trivially, but there various potential work-arounds.

The ordinary HDF5 library apparently does not even support concurrent *reading* of *different files* by multiple threads. Consequently NetCDF4, and the python bindings for either, will not support parallel writing.

If the output file is pre-initialised and has chunking and compression disabled, to avoid having a chunk index, then (in principle) concurrent non-overlapping writes to the same file by separate processes might work(?).

In more recent versions of HDF5, there should be support for virtual datasets. Each process would write output to a different file, and afterward a new container file would be created, consisting of references to the individual data files (but otherwise able to be read like a normal HDF5 file).

There exists a "Parallel HDF5" library for MPI. Although MPI might otherwise seem like overkill, it would have advantages if scaling up later to multiple machines.

If writing output is not a performance bottleneck, a multithreaded application could probably implement one output thread (utilising some form of queue data-structure).

[Edit:] Another option is to use [zarr](https://github.com/zarr-developers/zarr) format instead, which places each chunk in a separate file (an approach which future versions of HDF currently seem likely to adopt).

Answer (score 0):

If you are running in AWS, checkout HDF Cloud: https://www.hdfgroup.org/solutions/hdf-cloud.

This is a service that enables multiple reader/multiple writer workflows and is largely feature compatible with the HDF5 library.
The client SDK doesn't support non-blocking writes, but of course if you are using the REST API directly you could do non-blocking I/O just like you would with any http-based service.